Identifying FCM API Access Logs in Google Cloud Console
We are seeking guidance regarding an issue we've encountered while working to enhance the security of push notifications in our mobile applications. Specifically, we aim to introduce IP restrictions on our Server API Keys in the Google Cloud Console.
To identify the IP addresses currently accessing the FCM API, we attempted to review logs through the "Google Cloud Console / Logging / Log Explorer" for the relevant project. However, we have not been able to find any logs related to the FCM API.
We explored various sources and applied different filtering methods but could not locate any relevant log entries. Below are examples of the filters we’ve used so far:

resource.type="firebase_project"
resource.type="global"
protoPayload.serviceName="fcm.googleapis.com"

If anyone has successfully tackled a similar challenge or can provide insights into locating FCM API-related logs, we would sincerely appreciate your advice and assistance.
Thank you for your time and support.
